# Visiblity binding in WPF on a Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

While the data is loading, I want to hide the content of the WPF control (which is all contained in a grid) and display a loading trobber.

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsContentVisible}">
<!-- MyCustomView is hosted here -->
</Grid>
```

The data context of MainWindow is `MainWindowViewModel`, which also derives from `ViewModelBase`

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{}
```

*MyCustomView.xaml:*

```
<Grid>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Data}" />
<TextBlock>This shouldn't be visible during the 2.5 sec loading time, but it is!</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

*MyCustomViewModel.cs:*

```
public class MyCustomViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        IsContentVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsContentVisible");
        // Display loading.gif
        Data = await repository.LoadData();
        // Hide loading.gif
        IsContentVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsContentVisible");
    }
}
```

*ViewModelBase.cs:*

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private Visbility isContentVisible = Visibility.Visible;
     public Visbility IsContentVisible
     {
        get { return isContentVisible; }
        set { isContentVisible = value; }
     }

     protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }

        private ViewModelBase currentViewModel;
        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return currentViewModel; }
            set { SetProperty(ref currentViewModel, value); }
        }
}
```

and *repository.LoadData():*

```
Thread.Sleep(2500);
return "some text";
```

LoadData() is called as a command of a button

What am I doing wrong? If bind visiblity to the grid of the `MyCustomView` it works, but that's not the solution, since I'd have many views, and I only want to have binding in one place, the `MainWindow`.

Comment: Most likely IsContentVisible setter is not raising property changed event.

Comment: @MajkeloDev Hey, just debugged, and it is. The event is raised properly two times in LoadData() method

Comment: It's strange. Try to place some dummy textblock or something inside this grid instead of placing User Control for a test, so You will now if it's a problem of IsContentVisible property or it's a problem related to hosting User Controls

Comment: btw. You can place OnPropertyChanged("IsContentVisible") inside setter of this prop

Comment: I think that this is caused by Thread.Sleep - it doesn't care it's async it stops everything - You should go with Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep

Comment: Let's think.. You have two view-models deriving from base vm which has that property. You set that property for MyCustomViewModel instance and not on the MainViewModel instance. Hence it works for a Grid inside custom view but not main view. Moreover if you did something (although not a proper way, just giving hint for clarification) like this in main viewmodel: *IsContentVisible = Visibility.Hidden;    OnPropertyChanged("IsContentVisible"); await customVm.LoadData(); IsContentVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsContentVisible");* , then that would logically work.

Comment: I suppose the typo in "{Binding IsConentVisible}" is just a copying error, and is not your code?

Comment: @vnikhil I understand what are you trying to say. However, MainVM is not responsible for fetching the data, it's the job of the MyCustomVM, so I guess setting the property there wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: @PScr Sorry, yes, a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Correct. My point is just that your code is setting CustomViewModel.IsContentVisible property, however, you have bound MainViewModel.IsContentVisible property to your MainWindow Grid. How is that suppose to work. So your OnPropertyChanged is notifying property change to CutomView and not the MainWindow. In such case, there is no wonder that it's not working. My comments are here because you asked "What am I doing wrong?".

Comment: You say the `DataContext` for `MainWindow` is `MainWindowViewModel` which is either empty (as you show it) or contains some stuff you don't show us. If that is correct, the `Grid` in `MainWindow` cannot see `IsContentVisible` from `MyCustomViewModel`. As @vnikhil says. What happens if you put `Visibility="{Binding IsContentVisible}"` in the `Grid` of `MyCustomViewModel` instead?

Comment: Correct, I omitted part of the code, thinking it was unnecessary. I keep a reference to a currentVM in the mainVM, because of the routing, which switches the current view model. Edited the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
private Visbility isContentVisible = Visibility.Visible;
public Visbility IsContentVisible
{
    get { return isContentVisible; }
    set 
    { 
        isContentVisible = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("IsContentVisible");
    }
}
```

Comment: Irrespective of it's working or not, Property setter is the good place to call OnPropertyChanged method.